# DC Motor Difference Equation Digital Control System

Tags: dc-motor, control-system, analysis, system

This shows a DC motor drive with the voltage input.[image: DC Motor system]

And the discrete-time model is like this
[image]

The difference equation should be something like this:[image]

Where the C_1T is the inverse laplace transform of the transfer function of the 2nd order system G(s). C_2T is the inverse laplace transform of \$sG(s)\$. And C_3T is the inverse laplace transform of \$G(s)/s\$
The first difference equation is on its electrical subsystem and the second is the mechanical subsystem. 
How can I achieve that? 
I tried to do laplace transform equation (1). But my result is:

\$I(s)=\frac{E_a(s)-K_e\tilde{\omega}(s)+L_pi(0)}{sL_p+R_p}\$

I do not know how to put the G(s) to the difference equation.

I think the steps should be:

1. Make the ODE (I used eq.1)
2. Do the laplace transform (include the effect of initial condition)
3. Maybe change the parameters (?). I think this part could be the place to add the transfer function?
4. Substitute the zero-order-hold. Step input
5. Inverse laplace transform where only valid on t=0~T
6. Find the sample instant response (k-domain model)
7. Generalise the discrete-time model

It would be easy for me to directly use Z-domain transfer function and do the inverse Z-transform. But I want to know how to do it using steps I stated above.

I guess the step 3 should be something like this:

Step 3. \$ I(s)=\frac{s}{s^2+2s\zeta\omega_n+\omega_n^2} \frac{E_a(s)-K_e\tilde{\omega}(s)+L_pi(0)}{L} \$

Step 4. \$ I(s)=\frac{s}{s^2+2s\zeta\omega_n+\omega_n^2} [\frac{1}{s}\frac{e_a(0)-K_e\omega(0)}{L}+i_a(0)] \$

\$ I(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+2s\zeta\omega_n+\omega_n^2} [\frac{e_a(0)-K_e\omega(0)}{L}] + i_a(0)\frac{s}{s^2+2s\zeta\omega_n+\omega_n^2} \$

\$ I(s)=\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2s\zeta\omega_n+\omega_n^2} [{\frac{e_a(0)-K_e\omega(0)}{L\omega_n^2}}] + \frac{i_a(0)}{\omega_n^2}\frac{s\omega_n^2}{s^2+2s\zeta\omega_n+\omega_n^2} \$

Step 5. \$ i(t)= [{\frac{\frac{1}{L}e_a(0)-\frac{1}{L}K_e\omega(0)}{\omega_n^2}}]C_1 + \frac{i_a(0)}{\omega_n^2}C_2 \$

Step 6. 
on \$t=0-T : i(T)= [{\frac{\frac{1}{L}e_a(0)-\frac{1}{L}K_e\omega(0)}{\omega_n^2}}]C_{1T} + \frac{i_a(0)}{\omega_n^2}C_{2T} \$
on \$t=T-2T : i(2T)= [{\frac{\frac{1}{L}e_a(T)-\frac{1}{L}K_e\omega(T)}{\omega_n^2}}]C_{1T} + \frac{i_a(T)}{\omega_n^2}C_{2T} \$
on \$t=kT-(k+1)T : i((k+1)T)= [{\frac{\frac{1}{L}e_a(kT)-\frac{1}{L}K_e\omega(kT)}{\omega_n^2}}]C_{1T} + \frac{i_a(kT)}{\omega_n^2}C_{2T} \$

Step 7. \$i(kT)= [{\frac{\frac{1}{L}e_a((k-1)T)-\frac{1}{L}K_e\omega((k-1)T)}{\omega_n^2}}]C_{1T} + \frac{i_a((k-1)T)}{\omega_n^2}C_{2T} \$

 I tried it like this, but I think my step 3 is too random. Please help me to find the way to get the correct step 3.

Comment: I tried reading your question a few times and I am not sure if I get it. You are starting from equations (1,2,3), which is an ODE  system, and trying to obtain (4,5), which is a difference equations system? It seems that you also want the solution to follow those steps you listed, right? So could you maybe add all you have done so far so that people can just pitch in at what is wrong and where you are stuck instead of doing it all for you (few people will go over all those computations for you.)

Comment: Yes you are correct. I am trying to find the difference equation (4) and (5) using those steps. I already stated above that I already did step 1 and 2. But now I am stuck. I need some hint on how to get the (4) and (5).